# AngularJS copy value to another input on fly

Tags: angularjs, input, model

I need to bind 1 model to 2 inputs.
First input should be visible and i use it to set value to model

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ttl" class="form-control input-sm"/>
```

Second input hidden and i use it for form. I need to keep here actual value of model

```
<input type="text" name="ttl" value="{{ttl}}" class="form-control input-sm"/>
```

The problem is hidden input always empty.... How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Try ng-value not value maybe.

Comment: @Zyga doesn't work too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work for me (second input box only below):

```
<input type="text" name="ttl" ng-value="ttl" class="form-control input-sm"/>
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="ttl" ng-model="ttl" class="form-control input-sm"/>
```

I understand that you will hide that input yourself?

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/66chbuon/

Comment: After I put copy-field under ng-model field in html it works.... But is there any way to put copy field before ng-model? Is order so important?

Comment: @Anton Abramov Sorry, not sure what u mean? If you ask about the order of input elements in the DOM then it shouldnt matter no.

Comment: I mean when i try to fill first field, value copies to second. But if i try to fill second field, first doesn't change

Comment: @Anton Abramov If you use ng-value for second then it wont change. But you can put ng-model in both which will work then. But I though the second element will be hidden anyway so you wont be able to input anything?

Comment: Funny thing - actually in my project hidden field will be in form(right now it's not hidden for testing). Ng-model field will be under the form in div. So in that order field in form empty if i fill field in div, but if i fill form-field div-field will change value.

Comment: @Abraham Abramov Did you use ng-model on both? Can you post that HTML in your question if it still doesnt work.

Comment: @Anton Abramov you have different controller for the second element (ng-controller="DeckCtrl") than the first so the model is in different scope so they are not bind to the same thing if you know what I mean. If you remove that controller on your fiddle it works fine. The model you bind those fields to has to be in the same scope.

Comment: thanks, ok, i see now. Looks like i need to use custom js for this

Answer (score 0):

Simple use ng-model on both:-

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="ttl" class="form-control input-sm"/>
    <input type="text" name="ttl" ng-model="ttl" class="form-control input-sm"/>
```

Plunker:- http://plnkr.co/edit/fzCaGgqRmvV9UogzzTWk?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, but problem is not about hiding. I use type="text" here for example. Problem is about copy value from one field to another